# Series object not callable

Tags: python, numpy

I have an issue, where I am looking to find minimum of each element in series and a number. However python is throwing below error. I am relatively new to Programming so will appreciate any help in this regards

```
gap1 = dr.loc[data1]['gap']
pnl = 0
eod_ind=0
bandhigh = df1.ix[low]['Open'] + **min(upperband*abs(gap1),50.0)**
bandlow = df1.ix[low]['Open'] - lowerband*abs(gap1)
```

I get the following error

```
---> 60     bandhigh = df1.ix[low]['Open'] + min(upperband*abs(gap1),50.0)
 61     bandlow = df1.ix[low]['Open'] - lowerband*abs(gap1)
 62     #print bandhigh, df1.ix[low]['Open'],upperband,abs(gap1)

**TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable**
```

Comment: Have you defined `min` as a variable somewhere in your code?

Comment: Or maybe `abs`?

Comment: I have not applied **min** anywhere else but I have used **abs** at few places.

Comment: Have you used either of them as a *variable*, like: `abs = <some Series object>` somewhere else in your code? If you did, `abs` not longer represents the original Python's function, but your object. So, you should change the name of your variable to something else. If you can't find the solution, you could edit your question to include the rest of your code.

Comment: yes, got it. It is used as a series object. My bad!!!! It is a reserved word in python. Great thanks for your help